# No items displayed in list in tab

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I'm developing an app for ubuntu touch and I have tabs there. In one of them there is a list.

if I have this it don't show me any of items.

```
        Tab {
        objectName: "Tab3"

        title: i18n.tr("List")

        page: Page {
            ListView {

            ListItem.Subtitled {
                    text: "Item One"
                    subText: "21 m \t North"
                }
            ListItem.Subtitled {
                    text: "2nd item"
                    subText: "2.61 km \t South"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where is the mistake? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListViews get data from a ListModel, you don't directly add ListItems to them.  See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-listview.html#model-prop for more information about that.

A ListItem.* is used on the delegate property of your ListView, and will be used as kind of a template component, a new copy will be made for each item in your ListModel